# Summernote callback Image Upload complete, But Form submit post request file again

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, summernote

when I update file image in summernote, I use call back update image. It's OK.
But I submit form, file be sent again in requests, I want to submit form not send file again.

```
    $('.textarea-editor').summernote({
        height: 300, // set editor height
        minHeight: null, // set minimum height of editor
        maxHeight: null, // set maximum height of editor
        focus: true, // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
        callbacks: {
            onImageUpload: function (files, editor, welEditable) {
                sendFile(files[0], editor, welEditable);
            }
        }
    });
    function sendFile(file, editor, welEditable) {
        data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", file);
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Image/Upload",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (url) {
                $('.textarea-editor').summernote('editor.insertImage', url);
                //editor.insertImage(welEditable, url);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution :

```
    // onImageUpload callback
$('.textarea-editor').summernote({
  callbacks: {
    onImageUpload: function(files) {
      // upload image to server and create imgNode...
      $summernote.summernote('insertNode', imgNode);
    }
  }
});

// summernote.image.upload
$('.textarea-editor').on('summernote.image.upload', function(we, files) {
 data = new FormData();
        data.append("file", files);
        $.ajax({
            data: data,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Image/Upload",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (url) {
               $summernote.summernote('insertNode', url);
            }
        });

});
```

Documentation : https://summernote.org/deep-dive/#onimageupload

Comment: thank your answer, I callback successfully. My problem is when I submit form, file upload be sent again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove enctype="multipart/form-data" from your your form tag